# How long local(function) variables live in javascript

Tags: javascript

I came across to this example:

```
function countMyself() {
// Check to see if the counter has been initialized
if ( typeof countMyself.counter == 'undefined' ) {
    // It has not... perform the initialization
    countMyself.counter = 0;
}

// Do something stupid to indicate the value
alert(++countMyself.counter);
}
```

The snippet above demonstrate *"how to implement static local variable in javascript"*

I know that function variables are stored in the stack. Having `C` background I know that variables in the `stack` can be easily overwritten by consequent function calls.

This doesn't seem to be the case with javascript.

What rule specifies how long a local(function) variable live in the lifetime of the program?
I mean `stack` in Javascript must bear different semantic than `stack` in `C, C++`?

Comment: That's not really a local variable; it's a property of the function object itself. Functions are objects, and their properties last until something changes or removes them.

Comment: "Having C background I know that variables in the stack can be easily overwritten by consequent function calls." I'm not really sure what that means; it's not that they're "overwritten", which would imply a consistent memory location, it's that there's a new stack frame. In that sense JS is exactly the same, the difference being what Pointy said: this isn't a variable "local to the function" in the way you think it is. "Local function variables" in JS look and act roughly as they do in C.

Comment: @DaveNewton
In C to return reference to a local variable(object) is idiotic. In JS this i common practis.

Comment: @Hairi setting a property of a function is not common practice in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy
"something changes"? What `something` could be?

Comment: `delete countMyself.counter` or `countMyself = somethingNew` or ctrl+r

Comment: @Hairi Which is why I said "roughly", assuming the difference between GC/non-GC languages is fairly well understood. And the question was regarding "local variables", which despite different behavior, look and act *roughly* as they do in C. In C if one of your local variables references memory allocated in the function (more or less what a JS reference is) and you return the value of that reference, seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: @Hairi "What 'something' could be" -- anything that changes it, like `countMyself.counter = 42` or it's deleted or the code that's in the example or the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables at least exist as long as they are accessible. Through closures they could even stay forever:

```
   function noClosure() {
     let local = 3;
     //...
   } // local gets recycled here

   function closure() {
     let local = 3;
     return function inner() {
       return local; // <- closured
    }
  }

  var closured = closure();
  // local exists here:
  console.log(closured()); // 3
  // but now it might get recycled:
  closured = undefined;
```

In your snippet that isn't actually a local variable but rather the property of a global function object, which exists until it gets deleted, becomes unreferencable, or the engine stops executing:

```
  delete countMyself.counter; // property deletion
  countMyself = somethingNew; // unreferencable
```

Comment: (I added "unreferenceable" to cover when the function declaration is overwritten.)